# Multiple Stripe payment forms on single page

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to get token from stripe account. its working fine if there is only one form but not on multiple. I want to get the token for the form which is submited by user for that purpose i am sending ajax request to stripe by giving seperate id to every form. but its showing
Type error b is not defined. I want to know weather there is syntax error or not. if not than why its not working.

```
 <form id="stripe_form-1" role="form" method="post" action="#">
  <div id="#payment-errors-1"></div>
<input type="text" name="cc_number" value="">
<input type="text" name="cvv" value="">
<input type="text" name="ex_month" value="">
<input type="text" name="ex_year" value="">
<button id="sbtn-1 type=""button" onclick="StripeFunction1()" </button>
</form>

<form id="stripe_form-2" role="form" method="post" action="#">
  <div id="#payment-errors-2"></div>
<input type="text" name="cc_number" value="">
<input type="text" name="cvv" value="">
<input type="text" name="ex_month" value="">
<input type="text" name="ex_year" value="">
<button id="sbtn-2" type=""button" onclick="StripeFunction2()" </button>
</form>

<form id="stripe_form-3" role="form" method="post" action="#">
  <div id="#payment-errors-3"></div>
<input type="text" name="cc_number" value="">
<input type="text" name="cvv" value="">
<input type="text" name="ex_month" value="">
<input type="text" name="ex_year" value="">
<button id="sbtn-3" type=""button" onclick="StripeFunction2()" </button>
</form>
```

In java script

```
function StripeFunction1() {
    var form = $('#stripe_form-1');
form.find('#sbtn-1').prop('disabled', true);
Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler_1);
}
var stripeResponseHandler_1 = function(status, response) {
var form = $('#stripe_form-1');
if (response.error) {
    form.find('#payment-errors-1').text(response.error.message);
    form.find('#sbtn-1').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('<input>', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'stripeToken',
        'value': response.id
    }).appendTo(form);
    form.get(0).submit();
}
};

function StripeFunction2() {
    var form = $('#stripe_form-2');
form.find('#sbtn-2').prop('disabled', true);
Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler_2);
}
var stripeResponseHandler_2 = function(status, response) {
var form = $('#stripe_form-2');
if (response.error) {
    form.find('#payment-errors-2').text(response.error.message);
    form.find('#sbtn-2').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('<input>', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'stripeToken',
        'value': response.id
    }).appendTo(form);
    form.get(0).submit();
}
};
function StripeFunction3() {
    var form = $('#stripe_form-3');
form.find('#sbtn-3').prop('disabled', true);
Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler_3);
}
var stripeResponseHandler_3 = function(status, response) {
var form = $('#stripe_form-3');
if (response.error) {
    form.find('#payment-errors-3').text(response.error.message);
    form.find('#sbtn-3').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('<input>', {
        'type': 'hidden',
        'name': 'stripeToken',
        'value': response.id
    }).appendTo(form);
    form.get(0).submit();
}
};
```

When submit form its give typeerror b is not defined. Is there any mistake in syntax or is there any other method?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the issue? What's the _exact_ error message you're seeing (please copy/paste it)? Can you provide a screenshot of the developer console? There is no `b` reference anywhere in your code so the error message you provided is a bit surprising.

Comment: `TypeError: b is not defined` was from `https://js.stripe.com/v2/` . I have changed  `Stripe.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler_3);` to `Stripe.createToken({
       /* Card Details */
       number: $('#cc_number_3').val(),
       cvc: $('#cvv_3').val(),
       exp_month: $('#ex_month_3').val(),
       exp_year: $('#ex_year_3').val(),
       }, stripeResponseHandler_3);
    return false;
    }` And its working perfect.

Comment: how was this going after this post? @Sama

Comment: @uno looks like the previous comment says that "...it's working perfect" so, what more do you need to know? Although if it were me, I'd refactor this to remove the duplication.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for multiple stripe element forms on one page.  Just realized this is not stripe elements, i believe.  The JS is a bit different as I do not see any mounting going on in the javascript in the OP